# How to architect a multisite manager application?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, express, laravel

I'm trying to create a web application to manage multiple websites. I'm still not sure what platform to built upon this kind of app, Node.js or Laravel (PHP). I want the application to be scalable to millions of users with an average of 2 sites each.

Would you recommend SQLLite3, JSON or MYSQL for storing all individual site's data in separate files or a single database with all individual site's data?

How can I prevent users from hacking into each others site?

```
mainSite >
   Common
   Site1/config.json, content/posts/, layout/
   Site2/config.json, content/products/, layout/
   Site3/config.json, content/pages/, layout/
```

I'm still not final on the above structure. Please help me with getting started with this app.

Answer (score 0):

For scalable system you should use some system that will allow you easy redistribute resourses, so in this case i think node.js is better one, you could find many services that shares resourses for node.js

Answer (score 0):

Big plans. Lots of work. My advise start small.

Setup one website with laravel and see how far you get.
You will get one website with multiple pages.
Laravel is easy, scales, has tons of extensions and a living, vivid community.

You have the choice to clone the website and set the same thing up under a different domain or just a subdomain.

Comment: Yes, my bad is I get into too much detail before even starting a project. For the same reason, I had to drop some of my ideas because I found them not scalable for millions of users. I think I shouldn't think much or invest most time in planning stage to pixel perfect a web app very early.

Comment: Start with a simple website, login, edit articles. Then extend that.. or switch from make to buy and look for a existing system which fits your idea. There are also lots of open-source CMS systems around with good extensions: joomla, magento...